# Can't find hierarchy panel in 3ds max 2014

Tags: 3dsmax

I have been designing a building for my first video game, and I have had to switch over from 3ds max 2015 to 2014.

Everything has been going well, but now I have noticed that the hierarchy panel is nowhere to be found.

I really need to know what is going on and how to get it to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is visible at the main screen of 3ds max by default from 2015, and a lot of people did not like this change by the way.
Maybe Menu bar>>Tools menu>>New Scene Explorer ?